# How to implement thread-safe container with natural looking syntax?

Tags: c++, templates, thread-safety, c++14, temporary-objects

#### Preface

Below code results in undefined behaviour, if used as is:

```
vector<int> vi;
...
vi.push_back(1);  // thread-1
...
vi.pop(); // thread-2
```

Traditional approach is to fix it with `std::mutex`:

```
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(some_mutex_specifically_for_vi);
vi.push_back(1);
```

However, as the code grows, such things start looking cumbersome, as everytime there will be a lock before a method. Moreover, for every object, we may have to maintain a mutex.

#### Objective

Without compromising in the syntax of accessing an object and declaring an explicit mutex, I would like to create a template such that, it does all the boilerplate work. e.g.

```
Concurrent<vector<int>> vi;  // specific `vi` mutex is auto declared in this wrapper
...
vi.push_back(1); // thread-1: locks `vi` only until `push_back()` is performed
...
vi.pop ()  // thread-2: locks `vi` only until `pop()` is performed
```

In current C++, it's impossible to achieve this. However, I have attempted a code where if just change `vi.` to `vi->`, then the things work as expected in above code comments.

#### Code

```
// The `Class` member is accessed via `->` instead of `.` operator
// For `const` object, it's assumed only for read purpose; hence no mutex lock
template<class Class,
         class Mutex = std::mutex>
class Concurrent : private Class
{
  public: using Class::Class;

  private: class Safe
           {
             public: Safe (Concurrent* const this_,
                           Mutex& rMutex) :
                     m_This(this_),
                     m_rMutex(rMutex)
                     { m_rMutex.lock(); }
             public: ~Safe () { m_rMutex.unlock(); }

             public: Class* operator-> () { return m_This; }
             public: const Class* operator-> () const { return m_This; }
             public: Class& operator* () { return *m_This; }
             public: const Class& operator* () const { return *m_This; }

             private: Concurrent* const m_This;
             private: Mutex& m_rMutex;
           };

  public: Safe ScopeLocked () { return Safe(this, m_Mutex); }
  public: const Class* Unsafe () const { return this; }

  public: Safe operator-> () { return ScopeLocked(); }
  public: const Class* operator-> () const { return this; }
  public: const Class& operator* () const { return *this; }

  private: Mutex m_Mutex;
};
```

#### [Demo](https://ideone.com/UEhusW)

#### Questions

- Is using the temporary object to call a function with overloaded `operator->()` leads to undefined behavior in C++?
- Does this small utility class serve the purpose of thread-safety for an encapsulated object **in all the cases**?

---

#### Clarifications

For inter-dependent statements, one needs a longer locking. Hence, there is a method introduced: `ScopeLocked()`. This is an equivalent of the `std::lock_guard()`. However the mutex for a given object is maintained internally, so it's still better syntactically.
e.g. instead of below flawed design (as suggested in an answer):

```
if(vi->size() > 0)
  i = vi->front(); // Bad: `vi` can change after `size()` & before `front()`
```

One should rely on below design:

```
auto viLocked = vi.ScopeLocked();
if(viLocked->size() > 0)
  i = viLocked->front();  // OK; `vi` is locked till the scope of `viLocked`
```

In other words, for the inter-dependent statements, one should be using the `ScopeLocked()`.

Comment: There is a gap between `SafeThis::->` and the actual function call. After `SafeThis::->`, the temporary `SafeThis` object is useless, so the compiler may decide to destroy it before calling the actual function, hince release the lock before the protected function.

Comment: @ZangMingJie - No it may not. Don't answer in comments, especially if you mislead.

Comment: BTW, this is an interesting exercise, but I'd never actually use such a thing. It's too slow.

Comment: The one design issue with trying to make a collection class thread safe to consider.  Imagine if the first thread wants to check `.size()`, then obtain an iterator to it based on the result.  Having a thread safe wrapper doesn't resolve the race condition between the second thread calling `.clear()` or other change operation in between the calls of the first thread.

Comment: @selbie - That should be an answer.

Comment: @selbie - In fact, the vector should remain locked by any thread that possesses an iterator. There are too many different changes that would invalidate the iterator, and they don't all happen in an obvious way.

Comment: @Omnifarious - 100% agree. And it's often the aggregate data structure that needs locking, not the individual members of that struct. For example, if an LRU cache is built using list and map together, both collection objects need to get updated within the same lock.  Having a thread safe list and thread safe map together does not resolve my concurrency issue with the entire component.

Comment: May be of interest: https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/issues/924

Comment: In addition to Galik's link. [folly/Synchronized](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/docs/Synchronized.md) seems to be a full-featured implementation of the idea. Something similar is also part of [boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/thread/sds.html). I think the idea is good, though the implementation is tricky. *But* if done correctly, I only see benefits.

Answer (score 14):

Don't do this.

It's almost impossible to make a thread safe collection class in which every method takes a lock.

Consider the following instance of your proposed Concurrent class.

```
Concurrent<vector<int>> vi;
```

A developer might come along and do this:

```
 int result = 0;
 if (vi.size() > 0)
 {
     result = vi.at(0);
 }
```

And another thread might make this change in between the first threads call to `size()` and `at(0)`.

```
vi.clear();
```

So now, the synchronized order of operations is:

```
vi.size()  // returns 1
vi.clear() // sets the vector's size back to zero
vi.at(0)   // throws exception since size is zero
```

So even though you have a thread safe vector class, two competing threads can result in an exception being thrown in unexpected places.

That's just the simplest example.  There are other ways in which multiple threads attempting to read/write/iterate at the same time could inadvertently break your guarantee of thread safety.

You mentioned that the whole thing is motivated by this pattern being cumbersome:

```
vi_mutex.lock();
vi.push_back(1);
vi_mutex.unlock();
```

In fact, there are helper classes that will make this cleaner, namely lock_guard that will take a mutex to lock in its constructor and unlock on the destructor

```
{
    lock_guard<mutex> lck(vi_mutex);
    vi.push_back(1);
}
```

Then other code in practice becomes thread safe ala:

```
{
     lock_guard<mutex> lck(vi_mutex);
     result = 0;
     if (vi.size() > 0)
     {
         result = vi.at(0);
     }
}
```

Update:

I wrote a sample program, using your Concurrent class to demonstrate the race condition that leads to a problem.  Here's the code:

```
Concurrent<list<int>> g_list;

void thread1()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (g_list->size() > 0)
        {
            int value = g_list->front();
            cout << value << endl;
        }
    }

}

void thread2()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        if (i % 2)
        {
            g_list->push_back(i);
        }
        else
        {
            g_list->clear();
        }
        i++;
    }
}

int main()
{

    std::thread t1(thread1);
    std::thread t2(thread2);

    t1.join(); // run forever

    return 0;
}
```

In a non-optimized build, the program above crashes in a matter of seconds.  (Retail is a bit harder, but the bug is still there).

Comment: The main issue pointed out in your answer seems trivially fixable. It's a good point though. Can you please check the last section of the **Clarification**. I may have missed something, but to me it looks not much of an issue.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code that resolves the example race condition I cite above. Nor do I see how it could be "trivially fixable".

Comment: @iammilind - also wrote a sample program that crashes using your code.  See update above.

Comment: The reason why I keep harping on this is because you seem like a smart person with decent enough c++ experience. But threading is tricky, error prone, and threading issues are difficult to debug. Everytime I've seen someone try to get clever with threads and locking, it typically leads to worse bugs. If you introduced your Concurrent class to your team, you'd be introducing an unsafe pattern.

Comment: Yes, That's a design issue. Explaining that, I have demonstrated the "case-2". One needs to use `ScopedLock()` for inter depending statements.

Comment: And so now you have moments where the vector is thread safe and moments when it is not and not have a ScopedLock accessor, which won't work with std::mutex, only std::recursive_mutex.  If you were on my team, I would not let you check this in.  You'd be introducing a confusing pattern that is ripe with edge cases.

Comment: The container is always thread-safe, when used correctly. Isn't it? Yes, the pattern is slightly un-natural, when one has to use `ScopedLock()`. But that's anyways we will be doing using `lock_guard()`, if we don't use this library. Were we be in the same team, before taking your rejection to check-in this library, I would politely ask those edge-cases, where it will fail. :-) Currently I don't see any.

Answer (score 9):

This endeavor is fraught with peril and performance problems. Iterators generally depend on the state of the whole data structure and will usually be invalidated if the data structure changes in certain ways. This means that iterators either need to hold a mutex on the whole data structure when they're created, or you'll need to define a special iterator that carefully locks only the stuff it's depending on in the moment, which is likely more than the state of the node/element it's currently pointing at. And this would require internal knowledge of the implementation of what's being wrapped.

As an example, think about how this sequence of events might play out:

**Thread 1:**

```
 void thread1_func(Concurrent<vector<int>> &cq)
 {
       cq.push_back(1);
       cq.push_back(2);
 }
```

**Thread 2:**

```
 void thread2_func(Concurrent<vector<int>> &cq)
 {
       ::std::copy(cq.begin(), cq.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, ", "));
 }
```

How do you think that would play out? Even if every member function is nicely wrapped in a mutex so they're all serialized and atomic, you're still invoking undefined behavior as one thread changes a data structure another is iterating over.

You could make creating an iterator also lock a mutex. But then, if the same thread creates another iterator, it should be able to grab the mutex, so you'll need to use a [recursive mutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/recursive_mutex).

And, of course, that means that your data structure can't be touched by any other threads while one thread is iterating over it, significantly decreasing concurrency opportunties.

It's also very prone to race conditions. One thread makes a call and discovers some fact about the data structure that it's interested in. Then, assuming this fact is true, it makes another call. But, of course, the fact is no longer true because some other thread has poked it's nose in in between getting the fact and using the fact. The example of using `size` and then deciding whether or not to iterate over it is just one example.

Comment: In this code [expectedly] the iterator locks the mutex until the scope of the iterating object goes out. For that very purpose, `begin()`s are overloaded. I may have to check the specific case you mentioned though. Have you tested it BTW?

Comment: @iammilind - What is the actual type of `Mutex` in your code?

Comment: It can be QMutex or std::mutex. BTW did you try various scenarios with the ability be clarification in the question added?

Comment: @iammilind - The scenario I proposed already fails with `::std::mutex`. Because the program tries to grab a lock for both `begin` and `end` and ends up waiting forever for one of them.

Comment: If you have already ran, then can you put in a demo. Somehow, I am unable to compile it. BTW, the code in the question, doesn't grab any lock for `.end()`. I am also working on simplifying the code for the better usage.

Answer (score 6):

> Is using the temporary object to call a function with overloaded operator->() leads to undefined behavior in C++

No. Temporaries are only destroyed at the [end of the full expression](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/class.temporary#3) that made them spring to life. And using a temporary object with an overloaded `operator->` to "decorate" member access is exactly why the overloaded operator is defined the way it is. It is used for logging, performance measurement in dedicated builds and, like you self discovered, locking all member accesses to an encapsulated object.

> The range based for loop syntax is not working in this case. It gives compilation error. What is the correct way to fix it?

Your `Iterator` function doesn't return an actual iterator as far as I can tell. Compare `Safe<Args...>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);` with the argument list `Iterator(Class::NAME(), m_Mutex)`. What is `Base` when the argument in `Args` is deduced from `Class::NAME()`?

> Does this small utility class serve the purpose of thread-safety for an encapsulated object in all the cases?

It looks fairly safe for simple value types. But of course that is contingent on all access being done via the wrapper.

For more complex containers, where iterator invalidation comes into consideration, then making a single member access atomic will not necessarily prevent race conditions (as was noted in the comments). I suppose you may create an iterator wrapper that locks the container for the duration of its lifetime... but then you lose most of the useful container API.

Comment: What's "simple value types". Your last statement is not giving me a correct idea. Do you see any race conditions?

Comment: @iammilind - Think `std::array`

Comment: And as for seeing race conditions, I think selbie's comment summarizes it beautifully.

Comment: Well that's is more of a design issue. Once the `begin()` is called & stored in an auto variable, the mutex will remain locked till that scope. What's with `array`?

Comment: @iammilind - Like I already added in the answer, this forfeits most of the useful container API. `insert` and `remove` come to mind. The other answer explain the potholes much better.

Comment: Can you check the last edits of **Clarification** in my question. I am unable to get which issue you are exactly referring for `insert()` and `remove()`. Is it a design issue?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other issues, your assumption about `const` are also wrong. For many of the `stl` types, the `const` methods still require that the container is protected against modification for the duration of execution.

For that you require a shared mutex at least, and it also needs to be declared `mutable` so that it can be locked in the `const` path. At that point better be aware that the `std::shared_mutex` implementations out there also all violate the specification by introducing additional synchronization points due to a premature "exclusive first" scheduling strategy copied from boost. Treat them as a performance optimization with same constraints as `std::mutex`, don't rely on the specification.

When using const iterators (`cbegin`, `cend`) you also must be able to obtain a lock for the entire transaction.

So you require a `ScopedLock` for `const` access too.

---

Same verdict as the other responses, that inline `->` directly on `Concurrent` is a dangerous design choice. Typical pistol aimed straight at your own foot. Pretty much ensured that this will blow when refactoring naively from `.` to `->` operator.

Answer (score 0):

I can't resist to answer this, as I have been working on such a utility library for a few months now. Naturally, I think the idea is very good: it leads to much clearer and safer code.
To answer the questions:

1. As already answered: it does not lead to undefined behaviour because the temporary exists for the whole execution of the line of code in which it appears.
2. Your utility class can be used as universally as `std::lock_guard`. `std::lock_guard` is the go-to mechanism in C++11 to provide thread-safety, whatever the objects you are working with.

Many answers point out to possible misuses of your class (the "iterator from a `std::vector`" example), but I think these are irrelevant. Of course, you must try to limit the possibility of misuse, but you cannot ultimately remove them all. You get the same iterator problem using `std::lock_guard` anyway, and the purpose of your library is not to eliminate multi-threading mistakes, but to at least remove a few using the type system.

Some issues I see in your code:

- The standard library differentiate `std::lock_guard` and `std::unique_lock` and I think it is important to keep this distinction. The former for your daily mutex locking, the later to use with std::condition_variable for instance.
- You explicitly call `lock()` and `unlock()` on the mutex, you prevent the beneficial use of shared mutexes, as those have a `lock_shared` method for read-only access.
- You give access to the encapsulated object through const pointer / const reference. Read-only access still needs the mutex to be locked, because another thread could be modifying the object concurrently: you might be reading partly updated information.
- Your class is less flexible than the standard ones. For instance, `std::lock_guard` can accept an already locked mutex using the `std::adopt_lock` tag, and this can be very useful.

I'll be happy to point you to my own implementation if you are interested.

Comment: *"purpose of your library is not to eliminate multi-threading mistakes,"* -- spon on! Your answer seems interesting to me. I would be happy to hear more inputs on the implementation with possible code snippets.

Comment: @iammilind The thing is: if I add a snippet for every recommendation I have, I'll be posting my whole implementation! What about you look at [my code](https://github.com/LouisCharlesC/safe) and if you have specific questions I'll post the relevant snippets to make the answer more complete. Your feedback on the code is also very welcome.

Comment: Your code differs significantly from the one in the question, mostly in the design choice *not* to disguise the wrapped object as the plain type.  Still, it's not something I could recommend to include in a code base. It's still inviting to use it as duct tape around observed race conditions on single members, rather than investing the necessary effort to design atomic methods on a higher level interface. Feels like a quick and comfortable remedy to the developer, but it only provides enough to prevent the crash, not to fix the errors in the design.

Comment: @Ext3h I do not understand your first statement, but am interested in your feedback. Could you clarify what "not to disguise the wrapped object as the plain type" means ? To me, iammilind's code and mine are really similar.  
Also, it seems that some confusion comes from the fact that iammilind's question title mentions containers and so do his code examples. But his code sample and in-text questions are totally generic. I think the important idea here is that his code presents a generic tool that is a better basis for "atomic methods on a higher level interface" than plain mutexes are.

Comment: I mean amongst others the design choice of overloading `operator-> ()`, to disguise the implicit lock as semantically similar to the base type. And then confirming the suspicion by wrapping an `std::vector` as default example - a type which's interface is a lot, but it doesn't provide atomic transactions as it is primarily designed around the use of iterators.