# Fastest way to return object from queue but only if queue has it

Tags: c++

Suppose that I'm writing a simple thread safe queue

```
template <class T>
class ThreadSafeQueue
{
T pop()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex>{mutex};
        if (q.empty())
            //throw
        auto t = q.front();
        q.pop();
        return t;
    }
//...
```

I want `pop` to return an element from the queue but only if it has an element. Currently in m implementation, it throws an exception. But is throwing exceptions costly or not? Should I do like this?

I could also define a simple class like this:

```
PossibleElement{
 T t;
 bool has = false;
}
```

and return this element in `pop` but it'd involve copying `T` unnecessarily at least one more time when I have access it. Also, when it returns no element, it still creates it.

Checking, outside ThreadSafeQueue, whether `queue` is empty and only if it is, calling `pop` will also not work because in the middle of these two safe operations it could lose an object

Comment: Your `PossibleElement` reinvents a wheel called `std::optional`. Just use `std::optional` here. See your up to date, recent C++ book for more information on using `std::optional`.

Comment: Your `unique_lock` is a temporary.

Comment: Throwing exceptions can be relatively costly, so you shouldn't design your program to throw exceptions under normal circumstances -- rather, exceptions should be thrown only when something has gone badly enough wrong that performance is no longer of paramount concern (rather recovering cleanly from the fault is).

Comment: **Do not try to make thread safe collection classes**. They are inherently buggy and will have race conditions.  Rather just use the std:: collections and have your feature code use an appropriate lock at the scenario level instead of on each method of the class.  [See my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54781998/104458) for more detailed example on why trying to make a collection thread safe is risky.

Comment: @selbie thanks, I like this kind of advice, and I'm gonna do as you suggested. This is extremely helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @SamVarshavchik indicated in his comment, returning a `std::optional` is one good way to handle the contingency of the stack being empty when `pop()` is called:

```
std::optional<T> pop()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex>{mutex};
    if (q.empty()) return std::nullopt;
    auto t = q.front();
    q.pop();
    return t;
}

// Calling code
std::optional<string> myVal = myQueue.pop();
if (myVal) std::cout << "Popped: " << *myVal << std::endl;
```

Another possible way to handle it is to return a success/fail code instead, and copy out the popped object into a reference-parameter:

```
bool pop(T & retVal)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex>{mutex};
    if (q.empty()) return false;
    retVal = q.front();
    q.pop();
    return true;
}

// calling code
std::string myVal;
if (myQueue.pop(myVal)) std::cout << "Popped: " << myVal << std::endl;
```

Finally, in certain use-cases (e.g. where you don't need to store any default-constructed objects in the queue, or where the caller doesn't need to make a distinction between an empty queue and a queue with a default-constructed value in it) you could return a default-constructed object as a default/guard value:

```
T pop()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex>{mutex};
    if (q.empty()) return T();
    auto t = q.front();
    q.pop();
    return t;
}

// calling code
std::string myVal = myQueue.pop();
if (myVal.size() > 0) std::cout << "Popped: " << myVal << std::endl;
```