c++ thread safe queue data race or false positives from tsan
I can provoke a data race warning from g++ fsanitize=thread using the following queue implementation between Push() and Pop(ms,XXX). I can also provoke a double lock between the constructor and Push(). Do I have data race or am i getting false positives from the thread sanitizer?
template <typename T,uint64_t _count> class FixedQueueMT {
public:
    FixedQueueMT() {
        Reset();
    }
    explicit FixedQueueMT(std::function<void(T* element)> init) {
        Reset();
        Init(init);
    }
    void Init(std::function<void(T* element)> init) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(m_mutex);
        for(T& obj : m_array) {
            init(&obj);
        }
    }
    void Reset() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(m_mutex);
        m_read=0;
        m_write=0;
        m_closed=false;
        m_closeInstant=true;
    }
    bool IsClosed()const { return m_closed; }
    bool Empty()const { return m_write==m_read; }
    bool Full()const { return m_write==m_read+_count; }
    int Size()const { return (int)(m_write-m_read); }
    int Max()const { return _count; }
    void Close(const bool closeInstant=true) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(m_mutex);
        m_closed = true;
        m_closeInstant = closeInstant;
        mlock.unlock();
        m_cond.notify_all();
        m_cond_push.notify_all();
    }
    void Flush(std::function<void(T* element)> lf) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(m_mutex);
        while(m_write!=m_read) {
            lf(m_array+m_read++%_count);
        }
    }
    bool Pop(int milliseconds,std::function<void(T*element)> lf) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(m_mutex);
        while(m_write==m_read && !m_closed) {
            if(milliseconds!=-1) {
                if(m_cond.wait_for(mlock,std::chrono::milliseconds(milliseconds))==std::cv_status::timeout)
                    return false;
            } else {
                m_cond.wait(mlock);
            }
        }
        if(m_write==m_read || (m_closed && m_closeInstant)) {
            lf(0);
        } else {
            lf(m_array+m_read++%_count);
        }
        mlock.unlock();
        m_cond_push.notify_one();
        return true;
    }
    bool Push(std::function<void(T*element)> lf) {
        if(m_closed)
            FATAL("FixedQueueMT::Push called after close");
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(m_mutex);
        if(m_write==m_read+_count)
            return false;
        lf(m_array+m_write++%_count);
        mlock.unlock();
        m_cond.notify_one();
        return true;
    }

private:
#if SIZE_MAX==0xFFFFFFFF
    std::atomic<uint32_t> m_read;
    std::atomic<uint32_t> m_write;
#else
    std::atomic<uint64_t> m_read;
    std::atomic<uint64_t> m_write;
#endif
    std::atomic<bool> m_closed;
    std::atomic<bool> m_closeInstant;
    std::mutex m_mutex;
    std::condition_variable m_cond;
    std::condition_variable m_cond_push;
    T m_array[_count];
};

GCC version 11.4 on arm64 linux 5.15
EDIT: Minimal reproducible example below:
TSan gives me data race warnings and a double lock warning in the beginning when using Pop(ms,func) but not when using Pop(func). The difference is wait_for vs wait.
Compiled with:
g++ -fsanitize=thread -O1 -g -Wall -Wextra main.cpp -o main.exe
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <mutex>
#include <functional>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <signal.h>
#include <initializer_list>

template <typename T,uint64_t _count> class FixedQueueMT {
public:
    FixedQueueMT() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(m_mutex);
        m_read=0;
        m_write=0;
    }
    explicit FixedQueueMT(std::function<void(T* element)> init) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(m_mutex);
        m_read=0;
        m_write=0;
        for(T& obj : m_array) {
            init(&obj);
        }
    }
    void Pop(std::function<void(T* element)> lf) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(m_mutex);
        m_cond.wait(mlock, [this]() { 
            return m_write!=m_read; 
        });
        uint64_t index = m_read % _count;
        lf(m_array+index);
        m_read += 1;
        m_cond_push.notify_one();
    }
    bool Pop(unsigned int milliseconds,std::function<void(T*element)> lf) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(m_mutex);
        bool success = m_cond.wait_for(mlock, std::chrono::milliseconds(milliseconds), [this]() {
            return m_write!=m_read;
        });
        if(!success) {
            return false;
        }
        uint64_t index = m_read % _count;
        lf(m_array+index);
        m_read += 1;
        m_cond_push.notify_one();
        return true;
    }
    bool Push(std::function<void(T*element)> lf) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(m_mutex);
        if(m_write==m_read+_count) {
            return false;
        }
        uint64_t index = m_write % _count;
        lf(m_array+index);
        m_write += 1;
        m_cond.notify_one();
        return true;
    }
    bool PushBlocking(std::function<void(T*element)> lf) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(m_mutex);
        m_cond_push.wait(mlock, [this]() {
            return m_write < m_read + _count; // Not full
        });
        uint64_t index = m_write % _count;
        lf(m_array+index);
        m_write += 1;
        m_cond.notify_one();
        return true;
    }

private:
    uint64_t m_read;
    uint64_t m_write;
    std::mutex m_mutex;
    std::condition_variable m_cond;
    std::condition_variable m_cond_push;
    T m_array[_count];
};

sigset_t make_sigset(std::initializer_list<int32_t> signals)
{
    sigset_t set;
    sigemptyset(&set);
    std::for_each(signals.begin(), signals.end(), std::bind(&sigaddset, &set, std::placeholders::_1));
    return set;
}

struct TestStruct {
    std::vector<uint8_t> data;
};

void thread_one(FixedQueueMT<TestStruct,10>& q, std::atomic<bool>& stop) {
    int counter = 0;
    while(!stop) {
        bool succ = q.Push([&](TestStruct* element) {
            element->data.resize(2000);
            std::fill(element->data.begin(), element->data.end(), counter);
            counter += 1;
        });
        if(!succ) continue; // Just for illustration of intent
        /*
        q.PushBlocking([&](TestStruct* element) {
            element->data.resize(2000);
            std::fill(element->data.begin(), element->data.end(), counter);
            counter += 1;
        });*/
    }
}

void thread_two(FixedQueueMT<TestStruct,10>& q, std::atomic<bool>& stop) {
    std::vector<uint8_t> tmp;
    while(!stop) {
        q.Pop(100,[&](TestStruct* element) {
            tmp.resize(element->data.size());
            memcpy(tmp.data(), element->data.data(), element->data.size());
        });
        /*
        q.Pop([&](TestStruct* element) {
            tmp.resize(element->data.size());
            memcpy(tmp.data(), element->data.data(), element->data.size());
        });*/
    }
}

int main()
{
    const auto signal_list = make_sigset({SIGTERM, SIGSEGV, SIGINT, SIGABRT});
    pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &signal_list, nullptr);

    FixedQueueMT<TestStruct,10> q;
    std::atomic<bool> stop = false;

    std::thread t1 = std::thread([&] {
            thread_one(q, stop);
    });

    std::thread t2 = std::thread([&] {
            thread_two(q, stop);
    });

    int32_t last_signal = -1337;
    do
    {
        sigwait(&signal_list, &last_signal);
        std::cout << "Got signal " << last_signal << std::endl;
        stop = true;

        // Exit on sigint so ctrl+c still works
    } while (last_signal != SIGINT);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}

Output from TSan:
WARNING: ThreadSanitizer: double lock of a mutex (pid=149355)
    #0 pthread_mutex_lock ../../../../src/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_common_interceptors.inc:4240 (libtsan.so.0+0x53908)
    #1 __gthread_mutex_lock /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/11/bits/gthr-default.h:749 (main.exe+0x2a9c)
    #2 std::mutex::lock() /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_mutex.h:100 (main.exe+0x2a9c)
    #3 std::unique_lock<std::mutex>::lock() /usr/include/c++/11/bits/unique_lock.h:139 (main.exe+0x2a9c)
    #4 std::unique_lock<std::mutex>::unique_lock(std::mutex&) /usr/include/c++/11/bits/unique_lock.h:69 (main.exe+0x2a9c)
    #5 FixedQueueMT<TestStruct, 10ul>::Push(std::function<void (TestStruct*)>) /home/max/codes/FixedQueueMT/main.cpp:51 (main.exe+0x2a9c)
    #6 thread_one(FixedQueueMT<TestStruct, 10ul>&, std::atomic<bool>&) /home/max/codes/FixedQueueMT/main.cpp:97 (main.exe+0x2a9c)
    #7 operator() /home/max/codes/FixedQueueMT/main.cpp:136 (main.exe+0x2b97)
    #8 __invoke_impl<void, main()::<lambda()> > /usr/include/c++/11/bits/invoke.h:61 (main.exe+0x2b97)
    #9 __invoke<main()::<lambda()> > /usr/include/c++/11/bits/invoke.h:96 (main.exe+0x2b97)
    #10 _M_invoke<0> /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:259 (main.exe+0x2b97)
    #11 operator() /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:266 (main.exe+0x2b97)
    #12 _M_run /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:211 (main.exe+0x2b97)
    #13 <null> <null> (libstdc++.so.6+0xdc252)

  Location is stack of main thread.

  Location is global '<null>' at 0x000000000000 ([stack]+0x00000001fbf0)

  Mutex M11 (0x7fffffffdbf0) created at:
    #0 pthread_mutex_lock ../../../../src/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_common_interceptors.inc:4240 (libtsan.so.0+0x53908)
    #1 __gthread_mutex_lock /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/11/bits/gthr-default.h:749 (main.exe+0x3755)
    #2 std::mutex::lock() /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_mutex.h:100 (main.exe+0x3755)
    #3 std::unique_lock<std::mutex>::lock() /usr/include/c++/11/bits/unique_lock.h:139 (main.exe+0x3755)
    #4 std::unique_lock<std::mutex>::unique_lock(std::mutex&) /usr/include/c++/11/bits/unique_lock.h:69 (main.exe+0x3755)
    #5 FixedQueueMT<TestStruct, 10ul>::FixedQueueMT() /home/max/codes/FixedQueueMT/main.cpp:14 (main.exe+0x3755)
    #6 main /home/max/codes/FixedQueueMT/main.cpp:132 (main.exe+0x31dd)

SUMMARY: ThreadSanitizer: double lock of a mutex /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/11/bits/gthr-default.h:749 in __gthread_mutex_lock
==================
==================
WARNING: ThreadSanitizer: data race (pid=149355)
  Read of size 8 at 0x7fffffffdbe0 by thread T1 (mutexes: write M11):
    #0 FixedQueueMT<TestStruct, 10ul>::Push(std::function<void (TestStruct*)>) /home/max/codes/FixedQueueMT/main.cpp:52 (main.exe+0x2abc)
    #1 thread_one(FixedQueueMT<TestStruct, 10ul>&, std::atomic<bool>&) /home/max/codes/FixedQueueMT/main.cpp:97 (main.exe+0x2abc)
    #2 operator() /home/max/codes/FixedQueueMT/main.cpp:136 (main.exe+0x2b97)
    #3 __invoke_impl<void, main()::<lambda()> > /usr/include/c++/11/bits/invoke.h:61 (main.exe+0x2b97)
    #4 __invoke<main()::<lambda()> > /usr/include/c++/11/bits/invoke.h:96 (main.exe+0x2b97)
    #5 _M_invoke<0> /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:259 (main.exe+0x2b97)
    #6 operator() /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:266 (main.exe+0x2b97)
    #7 _M_run /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:211 (main.exe+0x2b97)
    #8 <null> <null> (libstdc++.so.6+0xdc252)

  Previous write of size 8 at 0x7fffffffdbe0 by thread T2 (mutexes: write M11):
    #0 FixedQueueMT<TestStruct, 10ul>::Pop(unsigned int, std::function<void (TestStruct*)>) /home/max/codes/FixedQueueMT/main.cpp:46 (main.exe+0x2e5f)
    #1 thread_two(FixedQueueMT<TestStruct, 10ul>&, std::atomic<bool>&) /home/max/codes/FixedQueueMT/main.cpp:115 (main.exe+0x2e5f)
    #2 operator() /home/max/codes/FixedQueueMT/main.cpp:140 (main.exe+0x2f01)
    #3 __invoke_impl<void, main()::<lambda()> > /usr/include/c++/11/bits/invoke.h:61 (main.exe+0x2f01)
    #4 __invoke<main()::<lambda()> > /usr/include/c++/11/bits/invoke.h:96 (main.exe+0x2f01)
    #5 _M_invoke<0> /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:259 (main.exe+0x2f01)
    #6 operator() /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:266 (main.exe+0x2f01)
    #7 _M_run /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:211 (main.exe+0x2f01)
    #8 <null> <null> (libstdc++.so.6+0xdc252)

  Location is stack of main thread.

  Location is global '<null>' at 0x000000000000 ([stack]+0x00000001fbe0)

  Mutex M11 (0x7fffffffdbf0) created at:
    #0 pthread_mutex_lock ../../../../src/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_common_interceptors.inc:4240 (libtsan.so.0+0x53908)
    #1 __gthread_mutex_lock /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/11/bits/gthr-default.h:749 (main.exe+0x3755)
    #2 std::mutex::lock() /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_mutex.h:100 (main.exe+0x3755)
    #3 std::unique_lock<std::mutex>::lock() /usr/include/c++/11/bits/unique_lock.h:139 (main.exe+0x3755)
    #4 std::unique_lock<std::mutex>::unique_lock(std::mutex&) /usr/include/c++/11/bits/unique_lock.h:69 (main.exe+0x3755)
    #5 FixedQueueMT<TestStruct, 10ul>::FixedQueueMT() /home/max/codes/FixedQueueMT/main.cpp:14 (main.exe+0x3755)
    #6 main /home/max/codes/FixedQueueMT/main.cpp:132 (main.exe+0x31dd)

  Thread T1 (tid=149359, running) created by main thread at:
    #0 pthread_create ../../../../src/libsanitizer/tsan/tsan_interceptors_posix.cpp:969 (libtsan.so.0+0x605b8)
    #1 std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State, std::default_delete<std::thread::_State> >, void (*)()) <null> (libstdc++.so.6+0xdc328)
    #2 __libc_start_call_main ../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58 (libc.so.6+0x29d8f)

  Thread T2 (tid=149360, running) created by main thread at:
    #0 pthread_create ../../../../src/libsanitizer/tsan/tsan_interceptors_posix.cpp:969 (libtsan.so.0+0x605b8)
    #1 std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State, std::default_delete<std::thread::_State> >, void (*)()) <null> (libstdc++.so.6+0xdc328)
    #2 __libc_start_call_main ../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58 (libc.so.6+0x29d8f)

SUMMARY: ThreadSanitizer: data race /home/max/codes/FixedQueueMT/main.cpp:52 in FixedQueueMT<TestStruct, 10ul>::Push(std::function<void (TestStruct*)>)
==================
==================
WARNING: ThreadSanitizer: data race (pid=149355)
  Write of size 1 at 0x7b7000000000 by thread T1 (mutexes: write M11):
    #0 __gnu_cxx::__enable_if<std::__is_scalar<int>::__value, void>::__type std::__fill_a1<unsigned char*, int>(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, int const&) /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_algobase.h:924 (main.exe+0x30df)
    #1 void std::__fill_a1<unsigned char*, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >, int>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned char*, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned char*, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> > >, int const&) /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_algobase.h:953 (main.exe+0x30df)
    #2 void std::__fill_a<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned char*, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> > >, int>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned char*, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned char*, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> > >, int const&) /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_algobase.h:969 (main.exe+0x30df)
    #3 void std::fill<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned char*, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> > >, int>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned char*, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned char*, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> > >, int const&) /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_algobase.h:999 (main.exe+0x30df)
    #4 operator() /home/max/codes/FixedQueueMT/main.cpp:99 (main.exe+0x30df)
    #5 __invoke_impl<void, thread_one(FixedQueueMT<TestStruct, 10>&, std::atomic<bool>&)::<lambda(TestStruct*)>&, TestStruct*> /usr/include/c++/11/bits/invoke.h:61 (main.exe+0x30df)
    #6 __invoke_r<void, thread_one(FixedQueueMT<TestStruct, 10>&, std::atomic<bool>&)::<lambda(TestStruct*)>&, TestStruct*> /usr/include/c++/11/bits/invoke.h:111 (main.exe+0x30df)
    #7 _M_invoke /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_function.h:290 (main.exe+0x30df)
    #8 std::function<void (TestStruct*)>::operator()(TestStruct*) const /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_function.h:590 (main.exe+0x2b2f)
    #9 FixedQueueMT<TestStruct, 10ul>::Push(std::function<void (TestStruct*)>) /home/max/codes/FixedQueueMT/main.cpp:56 (main.exe+0x2b2f)
    #10 thread_one(FixedQueueMT<TestStruct, 10ul>&, std::atomic<bool>&) /home/max/codes/FixedQueueMT/main.cpp:97 (main.exe+0x2b2f)
    #11 operator() /home/max/codes/FixedQueueMT/main.cpp:136 (main.exe+0x2b97)
    #12 __invoke_impl<void, main()::<lambda()> > /usr/include/c++/11/bits/invoke.h:61 (main.exe+0x2b97)
    #13 __invoke<main()::<lambda()> > /usr/include/c++/11/bits/invoke.h:96 (main.exe+0x2b97)
    #14 _M_invoke<0> /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:259 (main.exe+0x2b97)
    #15 operator() /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:266 (main.exe+0x2b97)
    #16 _M_run /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:211 (main.exe+0x2b97)
    #17 <null> <null> (libstdc++.so.6+0xdc252)

  Previous read of size 8 at 0x7b7000000000 by thread T2 (mutexes: write M11):
    #0 memcpy ../../../../src/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_common_interceptors.inc:827 (libtsan.so.0+0x6243e)
    #1 memcpy ../../../../src/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_common_interceptors.inc:819 (libtsan.so.0+0x6243e)
    #2 memcpy /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29 (main.exe+0x2ff4)
    #3 operator() /home/max/codes/FixedQueueMT/main.cpp:117 (main.exe+0x2ff4)
    #4 __invoke_impl<void, thread_two(FixedQueueMT<TestStruct, 10>&, std::atomic<bool>&)::<lambda(TestStruct*)>&, TestStruct*> /usr/include/c++/11/bits/invoke.h:61 (main.exe+0x2ff4)
    #5 __invoke_r<void, thread_two(FixedQueueMT<TestStruct, 10>&, std::atomic<bool>&)::<lambda(TestStruct*)>&, TestStruct*> /usr/include/c++/11/bits/invoke.h:111 (main.exe+0x2ff4)
    #6 _M_invoke /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_function.h:290 (main.exe+0x2ff4)
    #7 std::function<void (TestStruct*)>::operator()(TestStruct*) const /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_function.h:590 (main.exe+0x2e11)
    #8 FixedQueueMT<TestStruct, 10ul>::Pop(unsigned int, std::function<void (TestStruct*)>) /home/max/codes/FixedQueueMT/main.cpp:45 (main.exe+0x2e11)
    #9 thread_two(FixedQueueMT<TestStruct, 10ul>&, std::atomic<bool>&) /home/max/codes/FixedQueueMT/main.cpp:115 (main.exe+0x2e11)
    #10 operator() /home/max/codes/FixedQueueMT/main.cpp:140 (main.exe+0x2f01)
    #11 __invoke_impl<void, main()::<lambda()> > /usr/include/c++/11/bits/invoke.h:61 (main.exe+0x2f01)
    #12 __invoke<main()::<lambda()> > /usr/include/c++/11/bits/invoke.h:96 (main.exe+0x2f01)
    #13 _M_invoke<0> /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:259 (main.exe+0x2f01)
    #14 operator() /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:266 (main.exe+0x2f01)
    #15 _M_run /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:211 (main.exe+0x2f01)
    #16 <null> <null> (libstdc++.so.6+0xdc252)

  Location is heap block of size 2000 at 0x7b7000000000 allocated by thread T1:
    #0 operator new(unsigned long) ../../../../src/libsanitizer/tsan/tsan_new_delete.cpp:64 (libtsan.so.0+0x8f162)
    #1 __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<unsigned char>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) /usr/include/c++/11/ext/new_allocator.h:127 (main.exe+0x3914)
    #2 std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<unsigned char> >::allocate(std::allocator<unsigned char>&, unsigned long) /usr/include/c++/11/bits/alloc_traits.h:464 (main.exe+0x3914)
    #3 std::_Vector_base<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >::_M_allocate(unsigned long) /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_vector.h:346 (main.exe+0x3914)
    #4 std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >::_M_default_append(unsigned long) /usr/include/c++/11/bits/vector.tcc:635 (main.exe+0x3914)
    #5 std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >::resize(unsigned long) /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_vector.h:940 (main.exe+0x312c)
    #6 operator() /home/max/codes/FixedQueueMT/main.cpp:98 (main.exe+0x312c)
    #7 __invoke_impl<void, thread_one(FixedQueueMT<TestStruct, 10>&, std::atomic<bool>&)::<lambda(TestStruct*)>&, TestStruct*> /usr/include/c++/11/bits/invoke.h:61 (main.exe+0x312c)
    #8 __invoke_r<void, thread_one(FixedQueueMT<TestStruct, 10>&, std::atomic<bool>&)::<lambda(TestStruct*)>&, TestStruct*> /usr/include/c++/11/bits/invoke.h:111 (main.exe+0x312c)
    #9 _M_invoke /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_function.h:290 (main.exe+0x312c)
    #10 std::function<void (TestStruct*)>::operator()(TestStruct*) const /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_function.h:590 (main.exe+0x2b2f)
    #11 FixedQueueMT<TestStruct, 10ul>::Push(std::function<void (TestStruct*)>) /home/max/codes/FixedQueueMT/main.cpp:56 (main.exe+0x2b2f)
    #12 thread_one(FixedQueueMT<TestStruct, 10ul>&, std::atomic<bool>&) /home/max/codes/FixedQueueMT/main.cpp:97 (main.exe+0x2b2f)
    #13 operator() /home/max/codes/FixedQueueMT/main.cpp:136 (main.exe+0x2b97)
    #14 __invoke_impl<void, main()::<lambda()> > /usr/include/c++/11/bits/invoke.h:61 (main.exe+0x2b97)
    #15 __invoke<main()::<lambda()> > /usr/include/c++/11/bits/invoke.h:96 (main.exe+0x2b97)
    #16 _M_invoke<0> /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:259 (main.exe+0x2b97)
    #17 operator() /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:266 (main.exe+0x2b97)
    #18 _M_run /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:211 (main.exe+0x2b97)
    #19 <null> <null> (libstdc++.so.6+0xdc252)

  Mutex M11 (0x7fffffffdbf0) created at:
    #0 pthread_mutex_lock ../../../../src/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_common_interceptors.inc:4240 (libtsan.so.0+0x53908)
    #1 __gthread_mutex_lock /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/11/bits/gthr-default.h:749 (main.exe+0x3755)
    #2 std::mutex::lock() /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_mutex.h:100 (main.exe+0x3755)
    #3 std::unique_lock<std::mutex>::lock() /usr/include/c++/11/bits/unique_lock.h:139 (main.exe+0x3755)
    #4 std::unique_lock<std::mutex>::unique_lock(std::mutex&) /usr/include/c++/11/bits/unique_lock.h:69 (main.exe+0x3755)
    #5 FixedQueueMT<TestStruct, 10ul>::FixedQueueMT() /home/max/codes/FixedQueueMT/main.cpp:14 (main.exe+0x3755)
    #6 main /home/max/codes/FixedQueueMT/main.cpp:132 (main.exe+0x31dd)

  Thread T1 (tid=149359, running) created by main thread at:
    #0 pthread_create ../../../../src/libsanitizer/tsan/tsan_interceptors_posix.cpp:969 (libtsan.so.0+0x605b8)
    #1 std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State, std::default_delete<std::thread::_State> >, void (*)()) <null> (libstdc++.so.6+0xdc328)
    #2 __libc_start_call_main ../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58 (libc.so.6+0x29d8f)

  Thread T2 (tid=149360, running) created by main thread at:
    #0 pthread_create ../../../../src/libsanitizer/tsan/tsan_interceptors_posix.cpp:969 (libtsan.so.0+0x605b8)
    #1 std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State, std::default_delete<std::thread::_State> >, void (*)()) <null> (libstdc++.so.6+0xdc328)
    #2 __libc_start_call_main ../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58 (libc.so.6+0x29d8f)

SUMMARY: ThreadSanitizer: data race /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_algobase.h:924 in __gnu_cxx::__enable_if<std::__is_scalar<int>::__value, void>::__type std::__fill_a1<unsigned char*, int>(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, int const&)
==================
==================
WARNING: ThreadSanitizer: data race (pid=149355)
  Write of size 8 at 0x7fffffffdbe8 by thread T1 (mutexes: write M11):
    #0 FixedQueueMT<TestStruct, 10ul>::Push(std::function<void (TestStruct*)>) /home/max/codes/FixedQueueMT/main.cpp:57 (main.exe+0x29f9)
    #1 thread_one(FixedQueueMT<TestStruct, 10ul>&, std::atomic<bool>&) /home/max/codes/FixedQueueMT/main.cpp:97 (main.exe+0x29f9)
    #2 operator() /home/max/codes/FixedQueueMT/main.cpp:136 (main.exe+0x2b97)
    #3 __invoke_impl<void, main()::<lambda()> > /usr/include/c++/11/bits/invoke.h:61 (main.exe+0x2b97)
    #4 __invoke<main()::<lambda()> > /usr/include/c++/11/bits/invoke.h:96 (main.exe+0x2b97)
    #5 _M_invoke<0> /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:259 (main.exe+0x2b97)
    #6 operator() /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:266 (main.exe+0x2b97)
    #7 _M_run /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:211 (main.exe+0x2b97)
    #8 <null> <null> (libstdc++.so.6+0xdc252)

  Previous read of size 8 at 0x7fffffffdbe8 by thread T2 (mutexes: write M11):
    #0 FixedQueueMT<TestStruct, 10ul>::Pop(unsigned int, std::function<void (TestStruct*)>)::{lambda()#1}::operator()() const /home/max/codes/FixedQueueMT/main.cpp:39 (main.exe+0x2d4a)
    #1 bool std::condition_variable::wait_until<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock, std::chrono::duration<long, std::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> >, FixedQueueMT<TestStruct, 10ul>::Pop(unsigned int, std::function<void (TestStruct*)>)::{lambda()#1}>(std::unique_lock<std::mutex>&, std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock, std::chrono::duration<long, std::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > > const&, FixedQueueMT<TestStruct, 10ul>::Pop(unsigned int, std::function<void (TestStruct*)>)::{lambda()#1}) /usr/include/c++/11/condition_variable:151 (main.exe+0x2d4a)
    #2 bool std::condition_variable::wait_for<long, std::ratio<1l, 1000l>, FixedQueueMT<TestStruct, 10ul>::Pop(unsigned int, std::function<void (TestStruct*)>)::{lambda()#1}>(std::unique_lock<std::mutex>&, std::chrono::duration<long, std::ratio<1l, 1000l> > const&, FixedQueueMT<TestStruct, 10ul>::Pop(unsigned int, std::function<void (TestStruct*)>)::{lambda()#1}) /usr/include/c++/11/condition_variable:175 (main.exe+0x2d4a)
    #3 FixedQueueMT<TestStruct, 10ul>::Pop(unsigned int, std::function<void (TestStruct*)>) /home/max/codes/FixedQueueMT/main.cpp:38 (main.exe+0x2d4a)
    #4 thread_two(FixedQueueMT<TestStruct, 10ul>&, std::atomic<bool>&) /home/max/codes/FixedQueueMT/main.cpp:115 (main.exe+0x2d4a)
    #5 operator() /home/max/codes/FixedQueueMT/main.cpp:140 (main.exe+0x2f01)
    #6 __invoke_impl<void, main()::<lambda()> > /usr/include/c++/11/bits/invoke.h:61 (main.exe+0x2f01)
    #7 __invoke<main()::<lambda()> > /usr/include/c++/11/bits/invoke.h:96 (main.exe+0x2f01)
    #8 _M_invoke<0> /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:259 (main.exe+0x2f01)
    #9 operator() /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:266 (main.exe+0x2f01)
    #10 _M_run /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:211 (main.exe+0x2f01)
    #11 <null> <null> (libstdc++.so.6+0xdc252)

  Location is stack of main thread.

  Location is global '<null>' at 0x000000000000 ([stack]+0x00000001fbe8)

  Mutex M11 (0x7fffffffdbf0) created at:
    #0 pthread_mutex_lock ../../../../src/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_common_interceptors.inc:4240 (libtsan.so.0+0x53908)
    #1 __gthread_mutex_lock /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/11/bits/gthr-default.h:749 (main.exe+0x3755)
    #2 std::mutex::lock() /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_mutex.h:100 (main.exe+0x3755)
    #3 std::unique_lock<std::mutex>::lock() /usr/include/c++/11/bits/unique_lock.h:139 (main.exe+0x3755)
    #4 std::unique_lock<std::mutex>::unique_lock(std::mutex&) /usr/include/c++/11/bits/unique_lock.h:69 (main.exe+0x3755)
    #5 FixedQueueMT<TestStruct, 10ul>::FixedQueueMT() /home/max/codes/FixedQueueMT/main.cpp:14 (main.exe+0x3755)
    #6 main /home/max/codes/FixedQueueMT/main.cpp:132 (main.exe+0x31dd)

  Thread T1 (tid=149359, running) created by main thread at:
    #0 pthread_create ../../../../src/libsanitizer/tsan/tsan_interceptors_posix.cpp:969 (libtsan.so.0+0x605b8)
    #1 std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State, std::default_delete<std::thread::_State> >, void (*)()) <null> (libstdc++.so.6+0xdc328)
    #2 __libc_start_call_main ../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58 (libc.so.6+0x29d8f)

  Thread T2 (tid=149360, running) created by main thread at:
    #0 pthread_create ../../../../src/libsanitizer/tsan/tsan_interceptors_posix.cpp:969 (libtsan.so.0+0x605b8)
    #1 std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State, std::default_delete<std::thread::_State> >, void (*)()) <null> (libstdc++.so.6+0xdc328)
    #2 __libc_start_call_main ../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58 (libc.so.6+0x29d8f)

SUMMARY: ThreadSanitizer: data race /home/max/codes/FixedQueueMT/main.cpp:57 in FixedQueueMT<TestStruct, 10ul>::Push(std::function<void (TestStruct*)>)


A few observations: Your Empty, Full and Size methods are not thread-safe without holding the lock. Your Push should probably check (or re-check) m_closed after acquiring the lock.

Is the point of your Flush method to clear the queue? In that case, should it not notify everyone waiting to Push? Push is also not waiting for m_cond_push. In fact no method does

Please make it into a [mre] where you provoke it to get Tsan upset too.

False positives from sanitisers are extremely rare. You should always assume that it is your code that has a bug.

@Homer512 IsClosed() is also not thread safe.

This code is far away from being thread safe, in many ways. I'd trust the sanitizer (if you cannot spot the bugs yourself).

It is IMPOSSIBLE to make a thread safe collection class that exposes a "size" function, even with a mutex. The result of the function can't be trusted by the calling path as soon as the mutex is unlocked before return. It's better to just have a non-thread safe collection class and have a mutex that gates your scenario, and not just for the underlying collection.  Same applies to "Empty", "Full", and similar methods.

See my write-up here on this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54781998/104458

I see possible dead lock: calling arbitrary code in Push and Pop in a form of lf when lock is acquired. Why you are using atomics if you are using a mutex? Use of atomics requires much higher skill level ("lock free" or "wait free"), master use of mutexes first.

Can you copy paste TSAN report, with matching line numbers in code provided? Or better provide a living example on https://godbolt.org/z/11K9T6TK9

@JesperJuhl You mean because IsClosed() in combination with Reset() is about as useful as the Size() method? Or am I overlooking another issue with it?

One particular issue with the lf callback is this: What happens if the callback throws an exception? Then you have incremented m_read or m_write but your code will not execute notify_one(). You should then also wake up another reader in Pop() or writer in push to give them a chance instead

You should never call m_cond.wait_for without a predicate. condition variables can spuriously wake up, even if what you're waiting for hasn't happened.

Why are you using int32_t for signals? They are defined to be int.

@TedLyngmo thats a mistake. thanks!

@PepijnKramer thanks i added predicates in the edited example code

@Homer512 I now removed all that stuff with Empty, Full, Size, Flush and m_closed. I dont need it. I just need something simple that works when things are running as expected

@MarekR i removed the atomic in the updated example. thanks!

Can't reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/9jKMha74n :/

Can't reproduce also on my local machine with apple-clang 16 (clang-1600.0.26.6).

@MarekR on your godbolt if i choose x86-64 gcc 11.4 (same as i use on my own machine) i get a fatal error. Not sure how to read godbolt output though
